# Why was "self" chosen over "this" for the name of the first parameter of python methods?

Tags: python, naming, language-design, history, this

What was the rationale for choosing the name `self` instead of `this` when defining class methods in Python?

Yes, of course, you can name it whatever you want - but the widely agreed-upon name for the first parameter is very clearly `self`.

I ask because there was an [article](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2011/07/karin-dewar-indentation-and-colon.html) about Robert Dewar explaining why `:` was added to the end of block statement lines (e.g. `if foo:`, `def foo():`), where his wife, Karin, looked at it passively and mentioned it wasn't as readable without it.  So I wondered if there would be a similar explanation for Guido or the Python community to choose `self` over `this`.

Comment: Would `this` be a better choice? Some languages/people even have a preference for `me`.

Comment: I think the article you refer to is http://python-history.blogspot.com/2011/07/karin-dewar-indentation-and-colon.html; it was Karin Dewar, and for [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_(programming_language)).

Comment: Why the downvotes? Stupid question or not, it's still a valid one about software design. Man, SO is not the place it used to be...

Comment: I'm firmly in the "me." camp.  It's shorter and (on my keyboard) alternating hands.

Comment: Whoever voted to close as Primarily Opinion Based, this is a historical question able to be answered with a concrete, single, verifiable answer (as the accepted answer has done). I don't even know why I bother with this site anymore.

Comment: Qix, pretty everyone knows who would have incorrectly voted to close your question as he votes to close almost every question asked here. But the admins refuse to deal with him. So please just ignore it and him and don't let it put you off this site.

Comment: Interesting read provided by @jonrsharpe.

Comment: Yep, that's indeed the article I was talking about @jonrsharpe, thank you :)

Comment: @Qix _"this is a historical question able to be answered with a concrete, single, verifiable answer"_ The question can only conclusively be answered by **word of God** (i.e. whoever made the decision), and that makes the question not reasonably answerable by the community. The accepted answer still doesn't tell you **why** `self` was chosen; it merely points out that the name had been chosen earlier than you thought it was. Why it was chosen, you still don't know other than "**probably** because of its message passing paradigm", which is not an answer but a guess and thus opinion-based.

Comment: @Flater I respectfully disagree with your assertions. [Another similarly historical question of mine was very much answered in full by the community](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331388/why-was-the-caret-used-for-xor-instead-of-exponentiation), even though it was - as you call it - a "word of god" question. Just because it's a hard question to answer doesn't mean it's an impossible question to answer. The one thing it is certinaly **not** is opinion based. Further, question close votes should not be made based on the answers - that's quite backwards.

Comment: @Flater it looks like on the Wiki page it says "Also in this initial release was a module system borrowed from Modula-3;" I pulled up Modula-3, and I found references to self. Stronger evidence, perhaps, it just came with Module-3's module system. I find it an interesting challenge to maybe reach out to the people who were involved, if I really want to know. But I think it's answerable if someone can find the people who were involved.. Or maybe it's just like the Phil Collin's song, where the author will say it has no meaning he just chose it randomly.

Comment: @DanChase _"But I think it's answerable if someone can find **the people who were involved**"_ Those people are the "God" that's being referred to in the phrase "word of God".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The use of `self` can be traced back to [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), which is one of the eldest OO languages ([the oldest according to python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Smalltalk)) and influenced the python language designers:

- There is evidence of a direct influence of [Guido Van Rossum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum), since he was inspired for the early Python bytecode by the Smalltalk bytecode (see footnote 9 on page 26 of [this article](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2018/07/102738719-05-01-acc.pdf)):
- There is also evidence of an indirect influence in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls) that refers to a Modula-3 origin of the explicit `self`, [Modula-3 being influenced](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hosking/m3/reference/intro.html) by Smalltalk for its object an inheritance model, not to speak about [Niklaus Wirth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklaus_Wirth), the spiritual father of Modula who spent 2 years at Xerox Parc where Smalltalk was invented.

Smalltalk used `self` instead of `this`. It also used `super`. In that language, Kay probably opted for `self` because of its message passing paradigm: it reflects better the semantic to send a message to `self` rather than sending a message to `this`.

The C++ tradition of `this`, that Java inherited, is to be traced back to the [Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) language, which used a `THIS` reference (see the book "[The design and evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html)" by [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup), page 36). Interestingly, Stroustrup explains that he had also to decide between `this` and `self` and he decided to opt for the Simula terminology rather Smalltalk's one.